# Spark reading a CSV file - the column value starts with a number and ends with D/F

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use spark to read a CSV file, one of the field value in csv is `91520122094491671D`.
After reading, the value is `9.152012209449166...`.
I found that if a string starts with a number and ends with a D / F, that will be the result.
But I need to read the data as a string.
So what should I do?

This is the CSV file data.

```
tax_file_code|  cus_name|   tax_identification_number

T19915201|  息烽家吉装饰材料店|  91520122094491671D
```

The Scala code is as follows:

```
sparkSession.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true") 
  .option("inferSchema", true.toString) 
  .load(getHadoopUri(uri)) 
  .createOrReplaceTempView("t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds_tmp")

sparkSession.sql(
  s"""
     |  select  cast(tax_file_code as String) as tax_file_code,
     |          cus_name,
     |          cast(tax_identification_number as String) as tax_identification_number
     |  from    t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds_tmp
  """.stripMargin).createOrReplaceTempView("t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds")

sparkSession.sql("select * from t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds").show
```

The result is shown below.

```
+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------------+

|tax_file_code    | cus_name        |tax_identification_number|

+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------------+

|    T19915201    |息烽家吉装饰材料店 |     9.152012209449166...|

+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you sure it isn't like `9.15...E20`? In other words, it's in exponential form

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a CSV sample row and your Spark code

Comment: Ok, I've modified my question

Comment: Did you try not setting `"inferSchema"`? Or at least false?

Comment: Also databricks library is not needed in Spark2... `sparkSession.read.csv` works directly

Comment: Yes, it is indeed "inferSchema" that caused the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the trailing D / F are setting the schema interpreter to double or floats, and the columns are truncated, so you're seeing exponential values

If you want all columns to be strings, remove

```
option("inferSchema", true.toString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try :

```
sparkSession.sql("select * from t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds").show(20, False)
```

By setting truncate to false. If true, strings more than 20 characters will
be truncated and all cells will be aligned right

Edit:

```
 val x = sparkSession.read
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .csv("....src/main/resources/data.csv")

  x.printSchema()

  x.createOrReplaceTempView("t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds_tmp")


      sparkSession.sql(
        s"""
           |  select  cast(tax_file_code as String) as tax_file_code,
           |          cus_name,
           |          cast(tax_identification_number as String) as tax_identification_number
           |  from    t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds_tmp
  """.stripMargin).createOrReplaceTempView("t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds")

      sparkSession.sql("select * from t_datacent_cus_temp_guizhou_ds").show(truncate = false)
```

This will output as :

```
+-------------+----------+-------------------------+
|tax_file_code|cus_name  |tax_identification_number|
+-------------+----------+-------------------------+
|T19915201    | 息烽家吉装饰材料店|9.1520122094491664E16    |
+-------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: No, this does not work. and I found it because I added this line of code `option("inferSchema", true.toString) `. When I remove it, that's okay.

Comment: It should be 
 .option("inferSchema", true)

Comment: No, it should not be set

Comment: Would you mind telling me why we are not supposed to use it?